# Grails resources not loaded (css, js, images)

Tags: grails

I have a problem that seems to be know.

I'm using Grails to deploy an application, like always when you're working with software what worked yesterday doesn't work today.

My application was running smoother than milk, when all of a sudden my css wouldn't load, my images didn't load, and my js-files just went bananas and gave me tons of errors of this type:

```
GET http://www.project.com/static/js/project.js 404 (Not Found)
```

Now this has worked in the past, it just stopped without any clear explanation. The files it complains about are different, and sometimes it even works.

In development it works just fine, but "production" is messed up.

I googled the problem and it seems as if many people have experienced the same thing but I don't know what thread/answer is relevant for my Grails 2.1.1-version.

Cheers!

Comment: This question is far too broad for a specific answer. Please provide more details (log entires, application server/reverse proxy info and so on). You may also try clearing your browser's cache before performing further tests.

Comment: You can try a couple different things. 1) the inexplicable grails clean solution or 2) update the resource plugin version to the latest and greatest.

Comment: Show us the code, e.g. views/layouts/main.gsp.

Comment: @uchamp cleaning and re-deploying did make it a bit more stable, but now it's messed up again.

Comment: @JinzhaoWu This is how I link to a style sheer <link rel="stylesheet"
 href="${resource(dir: 'css', file: 'bootstrap.css')}" type="text/css"> (in the <body>-tag) and this is how I link to my js <script src="${resource(dir: 'js', file: 'jquery.js')}"></script>, that's done in the bottom of the page. Like I wrote in the initial question, this worked recently - it worked perfectly! But now the css won't load from time to time, and the same with js.

Comment: what version of the resource plugin are you currently using?

Comment: The version I'm using is 1.1.6 - I did an upgrade now...so I should have the latest and greatest

Comment: Ok so here's what I did, I went to the grails resource plugin page and added runtime ":resources:1.2.RC2" to my BuildConfig.groovy. It works perfectly now (again!) thank you all for useful input!